# Race Condition in Java With ReentrantLock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

In the following code a ReentrantLock has used to prevent generating odd numbers by the next() method. But the next() method generated odd numbers. But if i change it to nextWithTry it doesn't generate odd numbers. Can anyone explain the reason for this?

```
class Generator{

    Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
    volatile int c = 0;

    public int next(){

        l.lock();
        c++; c++;
        l.unlock();

        return c;
    }

    public int nextWithTry(){//This method works fine...

        try{
            l.lock();
            c++; c++;
            return c;
        }finally{   
            l.unlock();
        }
    }
}

class W implements Runnable{

    private Generator r;

    public W(Generator r){
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int x;

        while(true){
            if(((x = r.next()) % 2) != 0){
                System.out.println(x + " odd number Found");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Generator r = new Generator();

        W w1 = new W(r);

        new Thread(w1).start();
        new Thread(w1).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using java version 1.7.0_51 with eclipse JUNO. I tried without the volatile. Same thing happens.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I believe you have the right answer. There is an ordering problem but it not in an optimisation of the jit but in the code itself as you point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when something else increments `c` between `unlock` and `return`?

```
public int next(){
    //lock, exclusive access
    l.lock();
    //increment, all good
    c++; c++;
    //unlock, another thread can access
    l.unlock();

    //any number of other threads call `next` and can acquire the lock

    //return some random value
    return c;
}
```

When you use a `finally`, the `lock` is only released once the value of `c` to be returned is already on the stack:

```
public int nextWithTry() {
    try {
        //lock, exclusive access
        l.lock();
        //increment, all good
        c++; c++;
        //place the value of `c` to be returned on the stack (java passes by value)
        return c;
    } finally {   
        //unlock _after_ the return has been copied
        l.unlock();
    }
}
```

In fact, [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) directly recommends using `try..finally`:

> In most cases, the following idiom should be used:
>
> ```
>  Lock l = ...;
>  l.lock();
>  try {
>      // access the resource protected by this lock
>  } finally {
>      l.unlock();
>  }
> ```

This is to avoid issues like this as well as more serious ones where an `Exception` causes the `Lock` not to be unlocked.

Comment: Or you could store the value of `c` in a local variable before unlocking, then return that value, if you want to avoid a `try` block for some reason.

Comment: @stvcisco yes, certainly. But it is recommended by [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) to use `try...finally` to avoid issues with locks not being released.

Comment: @maamaa pun intended?